# sqrt-based filled ellipse pixel drawing function

Tags: vb.net, lua, draw, pixel, ellipse

I'm trying to make a function in Lua or VB based code to draw / plot a **filled** ellipse.
I don't have much knowledge about this math and I can use some help.

I Googled everything there is to Google about drawing ellipses with code but I can't find a good simple working example in VB or Lua for a filled one.

*On a previous post on this site I did get an answer about how to draw a normal ellipse but nothing came up for a filled one, that's why i make a new topic for a filled one.*

Here are a few websites I visited but I can't find a way to make a filled ellipse without redrawing already drawed pixels...

https://sites.google.com/site/ruslancray/lab/projects/bresenhamscircleellipsedrawingalgorithm/bresenham-s-circle-ellipse-drawing-algorithm

http://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/classes/6.837/F98/Lecture6/circle.html

http://www.blitzbasic.com/codearcs/codearcs.php?code=2817

http://hackipedia.org/Algorithms/Graphics/pdf/A%20Fast%20Bresenham%20Type%20Algorithm%20For%20Drawing%20Ellipses%20by%20John%20Kennedy.pdf

https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/49873666/

http://www.sourcecodesworld.com/source/show.asp?ScriptID=112

Here is the code I have for a normal ellipse (thanks to "Johnny Strings" for the VB version):

```
function DrawEllipse(xc,yc,w,h)
    local w2  = w * w
    local h2  = h * h
    local fw2 = 4 * w2
    local fh2 = 4 * h2

    xc = xc + w
    yc = yc + h

    local x  = 0
    local y  = h
    local s  = 2 * h2 + w2 * (1 - h)
    while h2 * x <= w2 * y do
        dot(xc + x, yc + y)
        dot(xc - x, yc + y)
        dot(xc + x, yc - y)
        dot(xc - x, yc - y)
        redraw()inkey()
        color(int(rnd()*255),int(rnd()*255),int(rnd()*255))
        if s >= 0 then
            s = s + fw2 * (1 - y)
            y = y - 1
        end
        s = s + h2 * ((4 * x) + 6)
        x = x + 1
    end
    x = w
    y = 0
    s = 2 * w2 + h2 * (1 - w)
    while w2 * y <= h2 * x do
        dot(xc + x, yc + y)
        dot(xc - x, yc + y)
        dot(xc + x, yc - y)
        dot(xc - x, yc - y)
        redraw()inkey()
        color(int(rnd()*255),int(rnd()*255),int(rnd()*255))
        if s >= 0 then
            s = s + fh2 * (1 - x)
            x = x - 1
        end
        s = s + w2 * ((4 * y) + 6)
        y = y + 1
    end
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Draw an ellipse sqrt-based function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30384333/draw-an-ellipse-sqrt-based-function)

Comment: @The Blue Dog, sorry for the similarity in this topic, but here I explicitly ask for code to draw a filled ellipse, on the other post I only got replies for a normal ellipse.. and maybe because i asked for 2 things (filled and normal ellipse) its best to make a new topic for the filled ellipse?

Comment: There are some algorithm here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322341/simple-algorithm-for-drawing-filled-ellipse-in-c-c

Comment: i'm working on it to translate it, if i have some trouble with that, can i then post my unfinished code here? or do i have to edit my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with for my CPU renderer in the past. It's very efficient and very simple too.

It relies on the mathematical definition of the ellipse, so the ellipse is drawn centered at x,y and has the width and height defined from the center, not from the other side.

The draw point function draws a pixel at the x by y point specified.

```
local function drawaxisalignedellipse(x,y,w,h)
    --n Defines the bounds of the horizontal lines which fill the ellipse.
    local n=w
    local w2=w*w
    local h2=h*h

    --draws the center horizontal line.
    for i=x-w,x+w do
        drawpoint(i,y)
    end

    for j=1,h do
        --The current top and bottom rows.
        local ra,rb=y+j,y-j

        --This loop removes 1 from n until it is within the shape
        while w2*(h2-j*j)<h2*n*n and n~=0 do n=n-1 end

        --Draws horizontal line from -n to n across the ellipse
        for i=x-n,x+n do
            drawpoint(i,ra)
            drawpoint(i,rb)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Hi Donald! thanks for the code, exactly what i was looking for. there are 2 small problems and i can't figure out how to alter the code to make it work correctly.. the first problem: if i want to make a circle 5 by 5 pixels (10,10,5,5) then the circle is 11 by 11 pixels.. the second problem: if i want to draw an ellipse like this "drawaxisalignedellipse(0,0,5,5)" then the ellipse is drawn outside the canvas, the left and top should be drawn starting from the border right?

Comment: The reason is because the height and width are defined from the center, not from the other side. The ellipse's position is defined in the center. I'm sorry, I should has said so. I do this because this is the most natural and useful way to define the position and size of objects. You can say x=x-w y=y-h w=floor(w/2) h=floor(h/2) if you'd like to do it in the standard programming way.

Comment: can i ask you one more thing if you don't mind? is the code for a "not" filled ellipse also that simple? the code i have for that is very long.. regards!